# Inserting pictures into Excel using VBA nested for loops causes subsequent images to shift vertically

Tags: excel, vba, image

I'm writing a VBA code that uses a nested for loops to insert pictures into a sheet in a grid pattern. I've specified cell increments in both the horizontal and vertical directions. The for loops insert all the pictures, but for some reason every next vertical step pastes the picture vertically lower and lower.

For example, the first picture is inserted with its top left corner in the top left corner of Cell A1. The second picture is then inserted a few pixels below cell A10. The third picture is then inserted even more pixels below cell A20, and the last picture is inserted way below the cell I've specified it to paste in.

```
Sub insertpic()

Dim img As Picture
Dim fPath As Variant

Dim rows As Integer
Dim cols As Integer

rows = Range("A5").Value 'total number of images to paste vertically
cols = Range("A6").Value 'total number of images to paste horizontally

startcol = Range("A3").Value 'start column to paste first image
startrow = Range("A4").Value 'start row to paste first image

vstep = Range("A8").Value 'vertical step
hstep = Range("A9").Value 'horizontal step

acol = startcol
arow = startrow

For i = 1 To cols
    For j = 1 To rows

        
        fPath = FolderName & "\" & fName 'not shown, but fPath changes to next image every loop
        
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath)
        
        With img
           .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(arow, acol).Left
           .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(arow, acol).Top
           .Placement = 1
        End With
        
        arow = arow + vstep
        
    Next j
    
    arow = startrow 'restarts next column at top row
    acol = acol + hstep 'shifts to next column over
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Inserting pictures horizontally are fine, its just the vertical direction that this is happening in. What I want is for the top left corner of every picture to be inserted at the top left corner of every cell that I specify. Can anybody figure out what's wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've tested your code without issues on M365. Please edit your post to share a screenshot.

Comment: What values do you have in `A3,A4,A8,A9`?

Comment: Its the weirdest thing, I ran my macro with Excel on my laptop screen and it inserted all images without any issue. For some reason, running the macro on a connected monitor creates the issue. Any ideas why?

Comment: A3 and A4 are just the column and row numbers for the very first cell to start pasting in. For me, its column 2, row 13.

A8 and A9 are 29 and 18, respectively. So every image will be inserted 29 rows below the last and 18 columns to the right of the last.